# Nodemon does not relaod after saving hbs files

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I used the `-e` when running my `app.js` file with nodemon.

```
nodemon app.js -e js,hbs
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,hbs
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
```

But it does not reload after saving any hbs file, no change will occur.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to run from root folder of your app like if you have appName 'weather' then run command `nodemon src/app.js -e js,hbs, etc extensions`

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your all hbs files in the folder where you have that app.js file.
After that, run again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. You just need to add -e js,hbs in the script and then close the server once using ctrl+c. Then restart the server and it will work fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).